# flying text from top to down

Tags: javascript, banner

I am trying to make a banner, where there should be some text going down from the top to the bottom. The code is just for a test, to see if it is working, so I will optimize it later. I have made this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  div.background {
    background: url(banner.jpg) repeat;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

  div.transbox {
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); 
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
  }

  div.transbox p {
    margin: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
  }
  #animation{font-size:20px; margin-top:40px; margin-left:50px;}
</style>

<script>

function loadImage() {
    $("#animation").animate({ marginTop: "300px" }, 1500 ).animate({ marginBottom: "40px" }, 800 );


}


</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadImage()">
    <div class="background">
      <div class="transbox" id="animation">
          <p>Text to fly in</p>
       </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I put an alert("test"); in the javascript code, I get the alert. But when I try to animate something, nothing happen. So I guess it is the animation code in the javascript, there is something wrong with? Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Best Regards 
Mads

Comment: You are missing JQuery include. Try adding these [JQuery 1.11.2](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) and [JQuery UI](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jqueryui). Alert is displayed because it belongs to JavaScript plain which is understood by all webbrowser since they have their own javaScript engine when installing them.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks a lot for the answer. Is it a stupid idea to use them today? I am thinking about the loading time and so on. Does it matter today?

Comment: These include are text minified, which means every characters is compressed to provide maximum load when charging the code. For my mind, I already use them because it makes you earn time when developping, and the loading time isn't that long to consider using JavaScript plain only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1 Include JQuery library.

## 2 Use absolute values in `animate` function:

```
$("#animation").animate({ top: 300 }, 1500 ).animate({ top: 40 }, 800 );
```

For this you need to make your `<div class="transbox" id="animation">` as `absolute` positioned.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Jquery here you just forget to include it into your code:
**Working Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  div.background {
    background: url(banner.jpg) repeat;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

  div.transbox {
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); 
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
  }

  div.transbox p {
    margin: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
  }
  #animation{font-size:20px; margin-top:40px; margin-left:50px;}
</style>

<script>

function loadImage() {
    $("#animation").animate({ marginTop: "300px" }, 1500 ).animate({ marginBottom: "40px" }, 800 );


}


</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadImage()">
    <div class="background">
      <div class="transbox" id="animation">
          <p>Text to fly in</p>
       </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

.animate() is the jQuery function. You need to include the jQuery library to use it.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  div.background {
    background: url(banner.jpg) repeat;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

  div.transbox {
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60); 
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
  }

  div.transbox p {
    margin: 5%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
  }
  #animation{font-size:20px; margin-top:40px; margin-left:50px;}
</style>

<script>

function loadImage() {
    $("#animation").animate({ marginTop: "300px" }, 1500 ).animate({ marginBottom: "40px" }, 800 );


}


</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadImage()">
    <div class="background">
      <div class="transbox" id="animation">
          <p>Text to fly in</p>
       </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answers. I found out how it works now.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just include jQuery lib in your page in header section

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```